# MySQLdb problem with Django and PyDev

Tags: django

I built my project with Django in Pydev. Every thing is working well. Now I configured PyDev to debug the project by adding runserver 8001--noreload
When I sent the Database engin to sqlite3 every thing is ok and I can debug the project. When I put the database engin to MySQL (my real DB) and try to debug, I get :
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading MySQLdb module: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

Please any help to resolve this problem. I installed the MySQLdb driver to my windows.
When I run the project normally it works, only I get this problem with Debuging.

Thanks

Comment: Please modify your question title to better match your actual question.  You're having trouble with Django debugging mode and MySQLDB with PyDev.

Answer (score 1):

In the *Debug Configurations* window, go to the *Environment* tab and add the following environment variable:

variable: **DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH** value: **/usr/local/mysql/lib**

And that's it.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed in Window -> Preferencs -> Pydev - Interpreter -> Libraries that... it said: C:\Python26\lib\site-packages when it actually says: C:\Python26\Lib\site-packages Lib instead of lib! Then it worked perfectly :) Finally MySQLdb has code completion.